# Angular 2/4 Onselect not getting

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to develop two drop downs in my Angular application. The first one is shop list and the other one is godown list. When I select a shop it will show its on data and selected shop list, but when I select godown it's not getting on the basis of the selected one.

Here I have two drop down boxes. There are so many questions on here but I could not get the correct answer anywhere.

TypeScript file:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._enqService.FetchPopulateOutlets().subscribe(outletsData => {
    let allShops = {
      ShopName: 'All',
      ShopID: 0
    }
    this.outletDetails = [allShops, ...outletsData]
  }, error => {
    console.error(error);
    this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
  });
  this._enqService.FetchGodownPopulateOutlets().subscribe(GodownsData => {
    let allGodowns = {
      GodownName: 'All',
      GodownId: 0
    }
    this.GodownDetails = [allGodowns, ...GodownsData]
  }, error => {
    console.error(error);
    this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
  });
}
onSelect(shopid: number) {
    this._enqService.FetchItemDetails(shopid, this.godownid, this.pageIndex).subscribe(itemsData => this.itemdetails = itemsData, error => {
      console.error(error);
      this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
    });
```

My HTML:

```
<span>
  <select class="form-control" name="outletDetail" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
    <option value="0" disabled>Select a Shop</option>
    <option *ngFor="let outletDetail of outletDetails" [value]="outletDetail.ShopID">{{outletDetail.ShopName}}</option>
  </select>
</span>
<span>
  <select class="form-control" name="godowndata" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
    <option value="0" disabled>Select a Godown</option>
    <option *ngFor="let godowndata of GodownDetails" [value]="godowndata.GodownId">{{godowndata.GodownName}}</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

I think the problem is in Onselect because here I use two parameter and in TypeScript I have use only one method.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`ngModelChange`** and **`ngModel`**

```
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selected" name="godowndata" (ngModelchange)="onSelect(selected)">
```

Comment: then my typescript ?

Comment: did it help you

Comment: No it did not get

Comment: look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-ngfor-vedoak?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: hey but my problem is not like that because i have 2 drop down one is working good another isnot working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177317/discussion-between-akhil-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **change** event

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" name="status" placeholder="select" (change)="onOptionsSelected()">
        <option *ngFor="let sta of accTypes" [ngValue]="sta">{{sta.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-ngfor-zucw96)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqc7bd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts


this is my stackblitz

Comment: here i use 2 Onselect and have pass only one method

Comment: your example has a lot of problems make sure your example working correctly @akhil

Comment: but your answer is almost correct but the problem is how to show the datas?

Comment: What data ? Is it about two  select element